# Second unique column using Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am using EF6 and in my customer table I like to have a column that is of type GUID and is unique. Doesn't have to be a primary. What I want to use this for, is to allow users to unsubscribe from emails. So I though every customer has a GUID under say `UnsubscribeEmailGuid` column and I send this in a form of a link, when they click it, I can figure out which customer it is, and set their preference to unsubscribe.

Now how can I using EF, define this column and make sure it has some value when a customer is created. I sort of tried:

```
    public Guid UnsubscribeEmailGuid{ get; set; }
```

and:

```
        Property(c => c.UnsubscribeEmailGuid)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasColumnAnnotation(IndexAnnotation.AnnotationName, new IndexAnnotation(new IndexAttribute {IsUnique = true}));
```

But it creates the customer with Guid `00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000`.

I am pretty sure I have to do something to the above setter property but my brain has stopped working!

Can someone please give me a nudge? Or maybe I am completely on the wrong track?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with this example, you have to initialize the object, for example i have the user class, and the property type GUID, so:

```
[Table( "users" )]
public class user{
    [Index(IsUnique = true)]
    public Guid UnsubscribeEmailGuid{ get; set; }

    public user(){
        this.UnsubscribeEmailGuid = new Guid();
    }
}
```

then, when you create a new entity of user, the constructor asign a value in UnsubscribeEmailGuid property. aditional to this you can use a DataAnotation for unique index.